# show a hidden div on reload after submit_form button click

Tags: php, javascript, forms, submit, contacts

I need to show a div upon page reload after the user clicks on the **submit form** button.

Specifically, I have a PHP contact form in a show/hide div. Clicking on *contact* shows and hides the contact form. Both the show/hide js and the php contact form work perfectly. 
When the user clicks *submit* -- the page reloads and the "message sent" is written in the contact form div. But when the page reloads, the form is in a div set to **display: none;** in the CSS -- which is how the page loads on default.

Upon *submit*, I need the page to reload and show the contact form in the hidden div. I'm not exactly sure where to start since all the javascript for the page reloads to default. Also since it's all PHP I can't set or call an anchor in the content_form div.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer a CSS solution over a JS one.

```
if ($form_is_valid)
    echo '<style type="text/css">#contact { display: block; }</style>';
```

**Edit:** Just to make things a little cleaner, I would suggest adding a class to your form if it was submitted successfully. Something like this:

```
$class = $form_is_valid ? ' class="submitted"' : '';
echo '<form method="..." action="..."' . $class . '>...</form>';
```

Then, you could just do a CSS definition that comes after the `display: none;` definition, like so:

```
form.submitted { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this to point $send_mail to a new div in CSS and $invalid back to the same div. Works well! 
Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please remember to mark this as your accepted answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some PHP code to write a script only if the form was sent successfully.

Then just echo a JavaScript to set the element display to block (similar to the following PHP code):

```
if($form_is_valid)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
       . 'document.getElementById("elementID").style.display = "block";'
       . '</script>';
}
```

Comment: So you could see what I did easily; it serves no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Breakthrough's answer should work fine, but I personally don't like putting any kind of success or error message in the markup, even hidden by CSS, if it's not really the case at the time of the page load. Since the page is reloading anyway, doing this would eliminate the need for any JavaScript or CSS at all to resolve this:

```
<?php if ($form_is_valid) include('SnippetFileWithSuccessMessageDivInIt.php') />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you the form is loaded with the submitted content, you can use javascript to detect the presence of text in the input fields. If any content is present, set display: block.

Comment: That could be problematic if there were default values in the form.

Comment: Yes. In that case, I suppose you could compare against the default values, but it definitely gets burdensome.